# Failling with "saml_idp" gem set up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, saml-2.0

I am trying to use "gem saml_idp" in my app but I am failling.

I am following this tutorial https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/05/31/rails-saml-identity-provider/ but I keep receiving the messages below from server everytime I make a GET request at http://localhost:3000/saml/auth.

```
Processing by SamlIdpController#new as HTML
Unable to find service provider for issuer 
Breadcrumb Controller halted via callback meta_data filter:Symbol has been dropped for having an invalid data type
Filter chain halted as :validate_saml_request rendered or redirected
Completed 403 Forbidden in 144ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/__meta_request/92c4c9d5-244f-4094-92e7-c7fed56de976.json" for ::1 at 2019-12-04 15:08:33 -0200
```

Does anybody know what is going on here ? Routes are:

```
get '/saml/auth' => 'saml_idp#new'
post '/saml/auth' => 'saml_idp#create'
```

Comment: The documentation says to act as a service provider you need to use the ruby-saml gem...have you added that?  Documentation here: https://github.com/saml-idp/saml_idp

Comment: Actually here I want to act as Identity Provider not Service Provider.

Comment: I want to emulate an IdP-Intiated connection. Built a SAML message and sent it to a SP.

Comment: I do not want to act as a SP which generates SAML Requests and react to SAML responses. In that case I do not need to use ruby_saml gem. Am I right ?

Comment: Finally, do you generate SAMLResponse to send to the SP?

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial describes the configuration necessary for an SP-initiated SSO flow. It won't be entirely applicable to you, since you are creating an idP-initiated flow. You may be seeing that "Unable to find service provider for issuer" error because the route you're visiting expects an AuthnRequest present (which would normally be generated and sent by the SP, to request a login for users on the idP... which would then respond to the SP with a SAMLResponse containing an Assertion). This happens because you're extending the idPController present in the gem. You won't need to do this unless you expect to respond to AuthnRequests from SPs.

This gem may still be useful to you. You should still be able to call SamlIdp::SamlResponse.new to build a SAMLResponse from an idP-initiated flow. The exact configuration depends on how you must communicate with your SP, so it is difficult to provide guidance here.